# Getting the uploaded image name using ImageField in Django and how to give autogenerated name to resized image before storing

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

**1.GETTING THE NAME OF UPLOADED IMAGE USING ImageField:** 
I am using ImageField to store the image getting from post request in a particular path. it is returning the image path instead of the image name

This is my model: image_ref is the global variable

```
class IMGResize(models.Model):
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='ImgResize', blank=True)
class Meta:
        db_table = 'imgresize'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image



    def save(self,force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
        if not self.image:
           return  
        super(IMGResize, self).save()   
        global image_ref
        image_ref = self.image 
        super(IMGResize, self).save()
```

Here it is generating some default name for the image, how can I get the name of the image?

**2. how to autogenerate the name to the resized image:**

Here in my previous model I am getting some image which I am trying to resize and store in some other path using some other model in the same models.py file.

This is my model:

```
from .resize_code import image_resize
    class Profile(models.Model):
        image = models.ForeignKey(IMGResize, related_name='profiles', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        image_width=models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
        image_height=models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=False)


        class Meta:
            db_table = 'profiles'
            unique_together=('name','image')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

        def save(self,force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
            global image_ref
            super(Profile, self).save()
            image_resize(self,image_ref)
            super(Profile, self).save()
```

here is my resize_code.py file:

```
def image_resize(self,image,force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
        if not image:
           return  
        img = Image.open(os.path.abspath(str(image)), 'r')
        img = resize_contain(img, [self.image_width, self.image_height])
        path='resized_images/contain.jpeg'
        img.save(path, img.format)
```

Here in resize_code.py I am hardcoding the name of the resized image instead of generating it everytime (path='resized_images/contain.jpeg')

Here is my serializer.py file:

```
class profilesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('name','image_width','image_height',)

    class IMGResizeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        profiles = profilesSerializer(many=True,read_only=False)
        image = Base64ImageField()
        class Meta:
            model = IMGResize
            fields = ('id','image','profiles',)

        def create(self, validated_data):
            profiles_data = validated_data.pop('profiles')
            image = IMGResize.objects.create(**validated_data)
            for profile_data in profiles_data:
                Profile.objects.create(image=image, **profile_data)
            return image
```

Thanks

Comment: The name of the uploaded file can be retrieved from your view itself.

Comment: How can i retreive image name in my view ??

Comment: maybe what you are looking for is [upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) in your model's field

Comment: i think noo because in upload_to i am specifying the path where the image to be stored but i want to get the image name with which it has been stored so that i can store the imaeg name in the database